# CGContextSaveGState error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am working on iphone app, at once it started showing me error, with no exception, i am really afraid of this error, can any one tell me why this is happening?

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue exists in iOS 7. It´s a known issue on which Apple is working on. Should be fixed in the next beta release.

Comment: @iOS does your App continue to run without problem even when this error shows?

Comment: yea app is working but this error is continusly repeating and repeating

Comment: I'm getting this when playing a youtube in a UIWebView, in the released version of iOS7. Is this an iOS issue in the release as well?